# How to extract a copy pasted table data from a outlook email body

Tags: python, excel, email, outlook

[Email Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxzKT.png)[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGmlj.png)extract a copy pasted table data from a outlook email body ,After extraction the fetched data not getting stored in same table format after first row each row got split into many rows of data . I can able to extract the data but unable save in same format which i get through email body.The sender not sending table as html data he just copy past the table from excel file there are some column which is empty.

```
# Import necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import os
import pathlib
import win32com.client
import zipfile
import shutil 
from io import StringIO
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

os.chdir(r"D:\Output")

#<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Mail data Fetching>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
# Define a set to store unique IDs of processed emails
processed_emails = set()

# Define the output directory path for saving email attachments
output_dir = pathlib.Path.cwd() / "D:\Output"

# Set up Outlook client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').getNamespace('MAPI')
inbox = outlook.getDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.items


# Define the time range for emails to be processed (usually within the last 24 hours)
start_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
start_date1 = start_date.replace(hour=16, minute=0, second=0).strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %p')
end_date = datetime.now()
end_date1 = end_date.replace(hour=23, minute=0, second=0).strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %p')
messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + start_date1 + "' And [ReceivedTime] <= '" + end_date1 + "'")


# Create a directory to save subject-specific data
base_output_dir = pathlib.Path.cwd() / "Output_Folders"
base_output_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

import os
from datetime import datetime

# List of subjects to process
subjects_to_process = ["NEW SLOT",]

# Function to create a unique subfolder for each ZIP file
def create_unique_subfolder(folder, filename):
    base_name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    subfolder_name = f"{base_name}_{timestamp}"
    subfolder_path = os.path.join(folder, subfolder_name)
    os.makedirs(subfolder_path)
    return subfolder_path

# Function to delete subfolders and files within a folder
def delete_folder_contents(folder):
    for item in os.listdir(folder):
        item_path = os.path.join(folder, item)
        if os.path.isfile(item_path):
            os.remove(item_path)
        elif os.path.isdir(item_path):
            shutil.rmtree(item_path)


import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

def extract_table_data_from_body(email_body):
    # Find the line that contains the table structure 
    start_index = email_body.find('Merchant')

    # Find the last occurrence of 'Physical Installation' to identify the end of the table
    end_index = email_body.rfind('--')
    
    # Check if both start and end indices are found
    if start_index != -1 and end_index != -1:
        # Extract the substring containing the table structure
        table_structure = email_body[start_index:end_index]

        # Use pandas to read the table
        try:
            df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(table_structure), sep='\t')
            
            # Create a CSV string from the DataFrame
            csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
            
            return csv_data
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error reading table: {e}")
            return None
    else:
        print("Start or end index not found.")
        return None


for subject in subjects_to_process:
    subject_output_dir = base_output_dir / subject  # Create a folder for the current subject
    subject_output_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    found_email = False  # Flag to check if an email with the current subject is found

    for message in messages:
        # Get the unique ID of the email
        email_id = message.EntryID

        # Check if this email has already been processed
        if email_id in processed_emails:
            continue  # Skip this email

        # Check for emails with the current subject (case-insensitive and partial matching)
        if subject.lower() in message.Subject.lower() and message.SenderEmailAddress != 'rxxxx@gmail.com':
            found_email = True
            body = message.body
            attachments = message.Attachments
            print(f"Found email with subject: {subject}")
            
            # Handle 'Pine Labs SLOT' subject
            if subject.lower() == 'new slot':
                # Extract table data from the email body
                table_data = extract_table_data_from_body(body)
            
                if table_data:
                    # Print a statement if table data is found in the email body
                    print("Table data found in the email body.")
            
                    # Create a unique CSV file with subject name and timestamp
                    csv_filename = f"{subject}_{datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}.csv"
                    csv_filepath = subject_output_dir / csv_filename
            
                    # Save table data to the CSV file
                    with open(csv_filepath, 'w') as csv_file:
                        # Write the table data to the CSV file
                        csv_file.write(table_data)
            
                    print(f"Table data stored in CSV: {csv_filename}")


            for attach in attachments:
                if attach.FileName.endswith('.xlsx') or attach.FileName.endswith('.xls') or attach.FileName.endswith('.csv'):
                    try:
                        attach.SaveAsFile(str(subject_output_dir / attach.FileName))
                        print(f"Saved attachment: {attach.FileName}")
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"Unable to save attachment '{attach.FileName}' due to error: {e}")
                elif attach.FileName.endswith('.zip'):
                    # Create a unique subfolder for this ZIP file
                    subfolder_path = subject_output_dir / f"{attach.FileName}_{datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}"
                    subfolder_path.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

                    # Save the .zip file within the subfolder
                    zip_file_path = subfolder_path / attach.FileName
                    attach.SaveAsFile(str(zip_file_path))
                    print(f"Saved attachment: {attach.FileName}")

                    # Extract the contents of the .zip file within the subfolder
                    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
                        for file_info in zip_ref.infolist():
                            extracted_file_name = subfolder_path / file_info.filename
                            zip_ref.extract(file_info, subfolder_path, extracted_file_name)

                    # Delete the original zip file after extracting
                    os.remove(zip_file_path)

                else:
                    print(f"Skipped attachment '{attach.FileName}' as it's not in the expected format.")
    
    # Check if no email with the current subject was found
    if not found_email:
        print(f"No email with subject '{subject}' received in the specified time period.")
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help without sharing the code, or the data, or **anything**?

Comment: @JohnGordon i have shared the code which i used for table  extraction

Comment: what is the problem? Do you get error message? We can't run it and we can't read in your mind - you have to show all details in question (not in comments) as text (not images)

Comment: eventually you could show image with table in outlook. Is this plain text or HTML? For plain text you could try to use `df.read_csv` with `sep="\s+"`. For HTML it may need `df.read_html` and it should find all `<table>` in HTML

Comment: @furas i have given the full code which i used for data extraction you may create sample table and paste it in email body with mentioned subject you can able to extract the table but it is not getting stored as table

Comment: @furas i have added table image sample it look like in email

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("ReceivedTime", True)
message = messages.GetFirst()

df=pd.DataFrame()
while message:
    #print(message.Subject)
    if message.Subject == 'Subject-Data':
        text_html = message.HTMLBody 
        html_body = BeautifulSoup(text_html,"lxml")
        html_tables = html_body.find_all('table')[0]
        df_list = pd.read_html(str(html_tables))
        df = pd.DataFrame(df_list[0])
        df.to_csv('temp.csv')
        break
    message = messages.GetNext()
```

This code fixed my issue of table extraction in formatted way i got the exact table stored in a csv after experimenting many concept this worked.